# How do I check for file existence in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix

How do you check if any file (the user chooses) exists in a certain place?

`$org` is a variable that I chose to set a path

```
if [ -e $org/$1]
then
echo "Do you want to overwrite"
exit 1
```

Do I use the if statement or getopts?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. There should be a space between `$org/$1` and `]`. The correct form is `if [ -e $org/$1 ]`. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`-f` checks if the path exists and is a file

`-d` checks if the path exists and is a directory

Comment: this is part of my bash script for creating a recycle bin,

is this syntax correct?

if [ -e $org/$1]

$org is the where the file originally existed. and I am doing this so if the the user is trying to a restore file and there is a file in the original destination with the same name, i want to ask the user 'do you want to overwrite?'

Comment: It may be worth noting that `-f` only detects regular files. It won't detect special files like device files or named pipes. It also won't match dead symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a space between `$org/$1` and `]`.

Try this:

```
if [ -e "$org/$1" ]; then
    echo "Do you want to overwrite"
fi
```

More information here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question when writing this answer. I'm not familiar with getopts, but in simple situations, the if statement with `-e "$org/$1"` works fine.